# Can't import from CrossType.Pure sbt project in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, scala.js

I'm trying to make Play framework project with Scala.js on frontend and one shared project. My sbt configuration is:

```
import sbt.Project.projectToRef

lazy val scalaV = "2.11.8"

lazy val shared = (crossProject.crossType(CrossType.Pure) in file("shared"))
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := scalaV,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.mediamath" %%% "scala-json" % "1.0"
    ),
    resolvers += "mmreleases" at "https://artifactory.mediamath.com/artifactory/libs-release-global",
    addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
  )
  // set up settings specific to the JS project
  .jsConfigure(_ enablePlugins ScalaJSPlay)


lazy val sharedJVM = shared.jvm.settings(name := "sharedJVM")

lazy val sharedJS = shared.js.settings(name := "sharedJS")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).settings(
  scalaVersion := scalaV,
  scalaJSProjects := jsProjects,
  pipelineStages := Seq(scalaJSProd, gzip),
  routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator,
  scalikejdbcSettings,
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    jdbc,
    cache,
    ws,
    evolutions,
    "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.39",
    "com.vmunier" % "play-scalajs-scripts_2.11" % "0.5.0"
  ),
  resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
).
  enablePlugins(PlayScala).
  aggregate(jsProjects.map(projectToRef): _*)

lazy val jsProjects = Seq(js)


lazy val js = (project in file("client")).settings(
  scalaVersion := scalaV,
  persistLauncher := true,
  persistLauncher in Test := false,
  autoCompilerPlugins := true,
  scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-feature"),
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.0",
    "com.mediamath" %%% "scala-json" % "1.0"
  ),
  resolvers += "mmreleases" at "https://artifactory.mediamath.com/artifactory/libs-release-global",
  resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
  addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
).enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin, ScalaJSPlay)
```

Everything is working fine but the problem is: I can't import anything from shared project in Scala.js and Play Framework project. Here is how my shared project structure looks:
[image]

And here is how I'm trying to import it:

```
import services.Encryptor
```

At compile time I got error:

> not found: object services [error] import services.Encryptor

How this issue can be fixed?

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not an expert in Pure (I use CrossType.Full myself), but that directory structure looks odd to me -- in my experience, the shared directory is usually a *peer* of the JS and JVM ones, not their container...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **never ever** (!) do this:

```
lazy val sharedJVM = shared.jvm.settings(name := "sharedJVM")
lazy val sharedJS = shared.js.settings(name := "sharedJS")
```

This creates new projects that are picked up by sbt, so the cross project does not hold the right projects anymore. See [docs](http://www.scala-js.org/api/sbt-scalajs/0.6.11/#org.scalajs.sbtplugin.cross.CrossProject) for details.

Instead, use `jsSettings` and `jvmSettings`:

```
(crossProject.crossType(CrossType.Pure) in file("shared"))
  // snip
  .jsSettings(name := "sharedJS")
  .jvmSettings(name := "sharedJVM")

lazy val sharedJVM = shared.jvm
lazy val sharedJS = shared.js
```

In your build, it seems that your `js` project does not depend on the shared project. So if course the shared project's contents are not available.

You need to

```
lazy val js = (project in file("client"))
  // snip
  .dependsOn(shared.js)
```

Comment: You answered correctly to my question but when I removed this part: lazy val sharedJVM = shared.jvm.settings(name := "sharedJVM")
lazy val sharedJS = shared.js.settings(name := "sharedJS") I've got error at compile time: No project 'sharedJVM'

Comment: I have clarified my reply. Please read the docs. CrossProject is just a tiny layer on top of sbt core infrastructure. If you do not understand what it does, nothing good will come from it.